# Hbase Region Load Stats not Found for Region Server

Tags: hbase

While writing data to Hbase, I am seeing the following logs at client end:

> AsyncRequestFutureImpl [ERROR] No ClientProtos.RegionLoadStats found
> for server=regionserver-1,16020,1662657306210,
> region=table1,,1662657579710.841db4e690a77a76e74b322f413b3c96.

I am successfully able to write data, but I am seeing these logs for every write request. Looks like this is probably because Region Load Stats are disabled for regions in the region servers. Is there any way to enable them and fix this logging?

**Hbase Client version :** 2.1.7

**Hbase Server version :** 2.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve it myself.
While initialising Hbase connections, we were setting 'hbase.client.metrics.enable' property to true in hbase Config. This works with 1.x client, but not with 2.x.
Setting this is to false worked, and we are not seeing any logging for 2.x client.